# How to convert bwa mem output to BAM format without saving SAM file

Tags: bioinformatics, sequence-alignment

I want to go straight from bwa mem alignment to BAM format as I don't need the SAM file and it takes up too much space. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For directly outputting a sorted bam file you can use the following:

```
bwa mem genome.fa reads.fastq | samtools sort -o output.bam -
```

Optionally using multiple threads:

```
bwa mem -t 8 genome.fa reads.fastq | samtools sort -@8 -o output.bam -
```

Comment: Ah, great solution if sorting is needed! I had tried this in the past but I was trying to pipe it though `samtools view` and _then_ into `sort`. Didn't realise you could go straight into `sort`.

Answer (score 12):

Found the solution. You just need to pipe the output from `bwa mem` into `samtools view` like so

```
bwa mem ref.fa in.fq | samtools view -bS - > out.bam
```

The `-` in samtools view tells it to read from `stdin`.

Comment: In my workflow, BWA output goes to MergeBamAlignment, so `samtools view` seemed lower overhead than `samtools sort`.  (Directly piping from BWA to MergeBamAlignment, as suggested [here](https://gatk.broadinstitute.org/hc/en-us/articles/360039568932--How-to-Map-and-clean-up-short-read-sequence-data-efficiently), failed for me.)